# Clickonce Office add-in assembly reference problem upon deployment

Tags: c#, assemblies, clickonce, vsto, gac

I have developed an Office 2007 C# add-in. It uses clickonce for deployment. On systems with Office 2010 all is ok but on a machine with XP SP3, NET 3.5sp1 and Office 2007, I get a strange assembly loading error.

My add-in does not directly reference `Microsoft.Office.Interop.SmartTag.dll`. This gets referenced by `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Commmon.v9.0.dll` - which IS referenced in my add-in.

When add-in is installed with clickonce an error is reported that the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.SmartTag.dll` could not be found in my add-in's local install folder. Both `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Commmon.v9.0.dll` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.SmartTag.dll` are in the GAC with correct versions.

I have used `Reflector` to try and detect the problem but it resolves `Microsoft.Office.Interop.SmartTag.dll` reference easily by finding the DLL in the GAC.

What are the possible reasons for my clickonce install to fail? The required assemblies are present but GAC is obviously not consulted.

I have found that adding `|vstolocal` to Manifest registry value makes everything work as expected but still I am wondering why was I getting the error in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying the PIAs as a prerequisite in the deployment, and the VSTO Runtime?

Comment: VSTO - yes, PIA - no. It turns out that PIAs is not required for Office 2007 as it is already installed by a typical install. Nevertheless, this is not the issue as the particular system got all prerequisites already installed.

Comment: You can't rely on the PIAs already being installed just because Office 2007 is installed. THis is true of Office 2010, but not 2007. Just FYI.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why I can't rely on preinstalled PIAs? After adding `|vstolocal`, my add-in works as expected. So everything *IS* already installed.